# Replace letter in string with names by indices

Tags: r, gsub

I have a vector with names

```
nms <- LETTERS[1:10]
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```

And I have a line as a rule

```
rule <- "X[,3]<=-0.85 & X[,10]>-0.95 & X[,5]>0.35"
```

I need to replace `"X"` with names with the same indices

`X[,3]` to `nms[3] ("C")` ...  `X[,10]` to `nms[10]  ("J")`

I want to get it

```
"C[,3]<=-0.85 & J[,10]>-0.95 & E[,5]>0.35"
```

Comment: what have you tried so far to solve this problem for yourself?  I think you can do this with `gsub()`, `match()`, and a `for` loop (so far I don't see an obvious way to solve it without a for loop)

Comment: First, I need to extract numbers from indices ..
I tried   readr::parse_number , gsub,  tidyr::extract_numeric ,    but it turned out to extract only one number, I don't really understand parsing string, so I asked the question right away what I want to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incomplete answer: start with

```r
r1 <- stringr::str_extract_all(rule,"\\[,([0-9]+)\\]")
n <- purrr::map_dbl(r1[[1]], readr::parse_number)
```

The first line extracts all of the bracketed expressions; the second retrieves the numerical value from each one.

Now a `for` loop where each time through the loop uses `sub` to replace the first `X` with the corresponding element of `nms` should work.

Comment: May I ask you to give a complete answer to the main question that was asked

Comment: Stack Overflow is supposed to be for *specific* programming questions (i.e. "I need to accomplish task X and I'm stuck on sub-task Y"), not "could someone please write code to solve the following problem for me".  I appreciate that it's frustrating to you to not get a complete answer (and you may feel free to downvote my answer), but I'm responding to the specific problem that you mentioned in the comments. (I've also voted to close as "needs more focus", i.e. "please rewrite the question to focus on a *specific* problem".)

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that it is possible to make it more concise, but I do not know how

```
nms <- LETTERS[1:10]
 rule <- "X[,3]<=-0.85 & X[,10]>-0.95 & X[,5]>0.35"
 
 r1 <- stringr::str_extract_all(rule,"\\[,([0-9]+)\\]")
 n <- purrr::map_dbl(r1[[1]], readr::parse_number)
 idx <- gregexpr(pattern ='X',rule)[[1]]
 for(i in 1:length(n))   substr(rule, idx[i], idx[i]) <- nms[n[i]]
 
 rule
[1] "C[,3]<=-0.85 & J[,10]>-0.95 & E[,5]>0.35"
```

Comment: You're welcome to accept your own answer as the best solution; you don't have to accept mine.

Comment: your answer was more helpful to me))
thank you, now I will formulate my questions more thoughtfully

Comment: FWIW I can see other ways to solve this problem but not necessarily any that are significantly more concise.

Comment: I will be glad if you share them